# how to use many @media in css

Tags: html, css, web

Under circumstance of giving compatibility to mobile devices, I have too many @media queries and as a result some aren't working, is there a syntax I am missing? or is the limitation of CSS.

in this code I am trying to hide a part of the image, but as the width of the mobile changes, the height needs to change as well, I've searched online for a list of viewport resolutions and with regard to that list, I've given media queries to every possible resolution I could find. BUT, all of these media queries aren't working as I've mentioned before, therefore I request the community for a solution.

The CSS Code:

```
.desktopimg {
  height: 486px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 223px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 211px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 393px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 234px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 249px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 324px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 324px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 294px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 444px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 444px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 884px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 444px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 884px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 444px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 834px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 444px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 444px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 810px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 444px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 314px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 504px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 290px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 432px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 260px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 428px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 257px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 412px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 248px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 411px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 247px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 238px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 186px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you want to use units like `vh` or `%` for this use case.

Comment: your order for the media queries would be wrong - you probably want to have your max widths in ascending order otherwise some later ones may override your earlier ones which is why it's not working as you expect. Although not sure why you'd want to limit the height of an image based on the width of the screen

Comment: @Pete yes, thank you after a while i've researched about a similar stackoverflow question. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Follow the following steps
1)Arrange the media query in decreasing order of `max-width`
2)Remove duplicate media queries
3)Use media query only for specific screen max width:425px,768pxand 1440px.
4) Use `screen` instead of `only screen` in media query statements.
Also in this part of the snippet your height remains same:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 444px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 444px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 884px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 444px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 884px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 444px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 834px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 444px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 444px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

and this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 324px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .desktopimg {
    height: 324px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

If you dont have to give changes there is no point of writting media query.
Kindly mark my answer correct if you find it correct.
Thanks in advance...